# Conectar o Laravel usando ubuntu num BD MSSQL

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia, alguém pode me ajudar? Estou tentando conectar meu projeto em laravel hospedado no apache2 do ubuntu 14, utilizando o php 7.1 num BD Microsoft SQL SERVER 2012. Eu já instalei as bibliotecas do FreeTDS e as configurei, conforme esse link: https://gist.github.com/gh…/97bf0b45a27d6b025d670752a7c62ec6 
.até consigo conectar pelo terminal com o comando: isql -v MSSQL sa 'XXXXXX' Mas quanto tento fazer um select no laravel aparece: " Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
could not find driver ". No .env do Laravel coloquei assim: DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv 
Agradeço toda a ajuda.

Comment: e no arquivo database.php?

Comment: Eu resolvi, como eu subi a aplicação com o git, eu não mudei o .env, então ele não reconheceu. Mas resolveu.